# Working with zeroes in Gaussian elimination

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

I am trying to find the null space of a matrix mod 2.
So far I have tried to implement basic Gaussian elimination.

Something happened that should've been very easy to solve but it's late and I can't think of a solution. Here's an example I made up:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

I've finished reducing the first column. I want to reduce the second column but there's a $0$ there.

In the end I am trying to find linear dependencies. Everything I've searched up has been for single solutions.

Edit: Apparently these are called free or pivot columns. If there were something in the second column below the zero it would be swapped.

Comment: @String My point is that there are other examples where that's not possible (I will modify my example)

Comment: The second column is already as reduced as possible ...

Comment: If my answer misses the point, please let me know! It is quite OK if you think so - I do not want to produce "spam" that misses the point in a question, so then I will either modify it or delete it. I can also elaborate it further, if that is what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I initially made a stupid error in my conclusion. It has been fixed now - the null space is 2D!

Forgive me, if I am too stupid to understand what you are asking! But in your example
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
I get the reduced row-echelon form to be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
The above corresponds to the equations (noting that we are calculating mod 2)
$$
\begin{align}
  x_1+x_2&=0&\iff&&x_1=x_2\\
  x_3&=0\\
  x_4+x_5&=0&\iff&&x_4=x_5
\end{align}
$$
and conlude that the nullspace has the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}s\\s\\0\\t\\t\end{pmatrix}=
s\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}+
t\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $s,t\in\mathbb B=\{0,1\}$.